# TSLint can't find custom module with custom d.ts file

Tags: typescript, webstorm, typescript-typings, tslint

I can't find a clear answer on this despite similar questions.

I am trying to use the `suncalc` module with TypeScript.  It doesn't have it's own typing file so I created one and placed it in my typings folder under `suncalc/suncalc.d.ts`

At the top of my file I have the following:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/suncalc/suncalc.d.ts" />
"use strict";

import * as moment from "moment";
import {SunTimes} from "suncalc";
import SunCalc = require("suncalc");
```

The code works fine and runs and wallaby is able to detect everything wonderfully.  However, TSLint (actually the TypeScript Compiler) in WebStorm is reporting that it can't find the module 'suncalc'.

I have tried playing with my `tslint.json` and `typings.json` as well as `tsd.json` but I can't seem to get them to remove the error.

Furthermore, if it's related when I run gulp it reports that it can't find `chai` or `it` or `describe` though WebStorm, TSLint doesn't have a problem with them.

I'd really like to get rid of the little red squiggly line beneath the word 'suncalc' in my project.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that the error you're seeing is actually an error from the TypeScript compiler, and not from TSLint.

Answer (score 3):

[Apparently](https://github.com/TypeStrong/tsify/issues/89) you need to be explicit with ambient modules.
The problem was in my d.ts file syntax.

You need to define the module not just then namespace, and be sure that the module name is wrapped in " ".
In my case I needed

```
declare module "suncalc" { }
```

instead of

```
declare namespace suncalc { }
```